# laravel doesn't detect my service provider

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm want create a packagist based in laravel,
I've created a laravel project,
I've created the next directory:

```
app/
...
packages/
- imfranq/
-- mypackage/
--- src/
---- Providers/
```

I want use the provider created in my Providers folder

My package `composer.json`

```
...
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Imfranq\\MyPackage\\": "src/"
  }
}
```

laravel `app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Imfranq\MyPackage\Providers\MyPackageServiceProvider::class,
]
```

I've run `make:provider` command and I've moved the file to my package folder

My `MyPackageServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
  dd('test');
}
```

Up to this point nothing works.

I try:

`composer dump-autoload` command

`composer cache:clear` command

`php artisan clear-compiled` command

nothing works

I try in laravel `package.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Imfranq\\MyPackage\\": "packages/imfranq/mypackage/src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "packages/imfranq/mypackage/src",
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

also

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Imfranq\\MyPackage\\MyPackageServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
},
```

Not work...

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu works in a clean project :(